# Nested Menu not responding correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there a way of changing the design so that:

1. The menu doesn't fully collapse when a new page loads, but instead just the active branch of the menu remains open and others are collapsed.
2. Change the scroll position in the menu on a page load, so that the currently selected menu item appears at the top of the menu scrollable area

My page, as it stands >>
https://startech-enterprises.github.io/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html

Both desired behaviours are exhibited correctly here:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops-local
   (this site reloads the whole page, on a menu click, like what my page currently does)
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#c_4
   (this site only loads the content section of the page, on a menu click)

Thanks

ST

NOTE The code in the link above has now been updated for part 1 of the question, based on the answers given below

**STRUCTURE OF LAYOUT PAGE:**

High Level Layout:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class = "middle section">
<div class = "left side-bar">
{% include navigation.html %}
</div>
<div class = "contents">
{{content}}
</div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONTENT PAGES using LIQUID/JEKYLL:**

Every content has the front matter like so:

layout: default

**Generated NAV BAR using LIQUID/JEKYLL:**

```
<ul class="treegroup">
  {% for item in include.nav %}
    {% if item.link %}
      <li {% if item.link == page.url | prepend:site.baseurl %} class="is-active"{% endif %} class="none"><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li {% if item.link == page.url | prepend:site.baseurl %} class="is-active"{% endif %} class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>{{ item.name }}</span></li>
    {% endif %}
        {% if item.tree %}
          {% include navigation.html nav=item.tree %}
        {% else %}  
        {% endif %}
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**YML NAV file used by LIQUID/JEKYLL**
(as used in Liquid/Jekll code above)

```
tree:
- name: Level 1
  link: /docs/level1.html
- name: Level 2
  link: /docs/level2.html
- name: Level 3
  tree:
  - name: Home  
    link: /docs/index.html
  - name: About
    link: /docs/about.html
  - name: Level 3.2
    tree:
      - name: Staff
        link: /docs/staff.html
      - name: People
- name: Level 4
  link: /docs/level4.html
- name: Level 5
  tree:
  - name: Blog
    link: /docs/blog.html
  - name: Level 5.2
    tree:
      - name: Branches & Loops
        link: /docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html
      - name: People
        link: /docs/people.html
```

**JAVASCRIPT on SIDEBAR:**
(to expand / collapse menu elements when clicking with mouse)
    /**
    * Expand or collapse menu
    */

```
"use strict";
(function tree() {
    let menu = document.querySelector('.toc');
    let elements = menu.getElementsByClassName("treeitem");
    let sibling = null;
    let expanded = false;

    eventListeners();

    function eventListeners(){
        // Listen for click
        Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
            element.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
                let e = null;
                ev.target.classList.contains("treeitem") ? e = ev.target : e = parent_by_selector(ev.target, "treeitem");
                sibling = nextByClass(e, "treegroup")

                sibling.classList.contains('is-expanded') ? expanded = true : expanded = false;  
                    if(expanded){
                        e.classList.remove("is-expanded");
                        sibling.classList.remove("is-expanded");
                    } else {
                        e.classList.add("is-expanded");
                        sibling.classList.add("is-expanded");
                    } 
            }, false);
          });
    }

})();

// WAIT TILL DOCUMENT HAS LOADED BEFORE INITIATING FUNCTIONS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tree);
```

**OTHER JS FUNCTIONS USED IN SCRIPT ABOVE**
(Helper functions)

```
// Find parent with given selector
function parent_by_selector(elem, selector, stop_selector = 'body') {
    let parent = elem;
    while (true) {
      if (parent.classList.contains(stop_selector)) break;
      if (parent.classList.contains(selector)) break;
      parent = parent.parentElement; // get upper parent and check again
    }
    if (parent.classList.contains(stop_selector)) parent = null; // when parent is a tag 'body' -> parent not found
    return parent;
  };

// Find child with given selector
function child_by_selector(elem, selector) {
    let children = elem.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].className &&
            children[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(selector) >= 0) {
            return children[i];
         }
     }
     for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         let child = child_by_selector(children[i], selector);
         if (child !== null) {
             return child;
         }
     }
     return null;
}

// Find next sibling of particular class
function nextByClass(elem, cls) {
    while (elem = elem.nextElementSibling) {
        if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
            return elem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Find previous sibling of particular class
function previousByClass(elem, cls) {
    while (elem = elem.previousElementSibling) {
        if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
            return elem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Sibling class found?
function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    let str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    let testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}
```

**CSS used for SIDEBAR:**

```
/* Collapsable */
ul.toc > ul .treegroup:not(.is-expanded){
  display: none;
}

/* Chevron */
.chevron{
height:0.5rem;
width: 0.5rem;

}
.tree-expander{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.tree-indicator{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  top: 6px;
  left: -1.5em;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.treeitem.is-expanded > .tree-expander > .tree-indicator {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `expandEntryOnLoad` for expanding the corresponding group. I assumed that in the end solution there will be no same links in different menus.

For scrolling: Search for "scroll to element" and you should be able to implement it. :)

Tip: Try to create more minimal, reproducible and runnable code snippets in your questions. That way people are more willing to help you, since it's less time consuming. Check this: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

```js
// Move this method to "tree". I just put it at the top so it's easy to find.
function expandEntryOnLoad() {
  // Just for testing. Use the target below in production.
  let target = "/docs/people.html";
  // let target = window.location.pathname;

  // Find first "a" with the target as href
  let a = [...document.querySelectorAll(".toc a")].find(a => a.pathname === target);
  // Expand all tree group parents.
  if (a) {
    let parent = a;
    while (parent = parent.parentElement.closest(".treegroup")) parent.classList.add("is-expanded")
  }
}

// Find parent with given selector
function parent_by_selector(elem, cls, stop_selector = 'body') {
  // NOTE: Simplified since there is already a function for that.
  return elem.closest("." + cls)
};

// Find next sibling of particular class
function nextByClass(elem, cls) {
  while (elem = elem.nextElementSibling) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
      return elem;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Find previous sibling of particular class
function previousByClass(elem, cls) {
  while (elem = elem.previousElementSibling) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
      return elem;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Sibling class found?
function hasClass(elem, cls) {
  // NOTE: simplified, since there is an easier way to check this. You are already using it at several places.
  return elem.classList.contains(cls);
}

"use strict";

function tree() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.toc');
  let elements = menu.getElementsByClassName("treeitem");
  let sibling = null;
  let expanded = false;

  eventListeners();

  function eventListeners() {
    // Listen for click
    Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        let e = null;
        ev.target.classList.contains("treeitem") ? e = ev.target : e = parent_by_selector(ev.target, "treeitem");
        sibling = nextByClass(e, "treegroup")

        sibling.classList.contains('is-expanded') ? expanded = true : expanded = false;
        if (expanded) {
          e.classList.remove("is-expanded");
          sibling.classList.remove("is-expanded");
        } else {
          e.classList.add("is-expanded");
          sibling.classList.add("is-expanded");
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }

  expandEntryOnLoad();
};

// WAIT TILL DOCUMENT HAS LOADED BEFORE INITIATING FUNCTIONS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tree());
```

```css
/* Collapsable */

ul.toc>ul .treegroup:not(.is-expanded) {
  display: none;
}


/* Chevron */

.chevron {
  height: 0.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
}

.tree-expander {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.tree-indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  top: 6px;
  left: -1.5em;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.treeitem.is-expanded>.tree-expander>.tree-indicator {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="toc is-vertically-scrollable has-flex-grow has-flex-shrink">
  <ul class="treegroup">
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level1.html">Level 1</a></li>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level2.html">Level 2</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 3</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 3.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/staff.html">Staff</a></li>
        <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>People</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level4.html">Level 4</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html">Branches &amp; Loops and everthing else in the world that is in between</a></li>
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/people.html">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level4.html">Level 6</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 7</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html">Branches &amp; Loops</a></li>
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/people.html">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level4.html">Level 8</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 9</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html">Branches &amp; Loops</a></li>
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/people.html">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level4.html">Level 10</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 11</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html">Branches &amp; Loops</a></li>
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/people.html">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class="none"><a href="/docs/level4.html">Level 12</a></li>
    <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 13</span>
    </li>
    <ul class="treegroup">
      <li class="none"><a href="/docs/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="treeitem"><span class="tree-expander"><span class="tree-indicator"><img src="/../docs/assets/images/chevron.png" class="chevron"></span>Level 5.2</span>
      </li>
      <ul class="treegroup">
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html">Branches &amp; Loops</a></li>
        <li class="none"><a href="/docs/people.html">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The expanding of the branch, and collapsing of the others works really well! I've just implemented it. I will look for the scroll to element solution from the advice given too, and let you know when that's been incorporated too. I've tried again to update your answer to this question!

Comment: Accepted answer. I just changed the document part of document.querySelectorAll to document.querySelector('.toc').querySelectorAll, to narrow the 'a' tag search

Comment: `querySelector[All]` is actually a quite powerful method. Instead of calling it twice, you can also do `document.querySelectorAll(".toc a")`, which means "get all `a` elements within `.toc`". I changed it in my post. I do actually prefer it over all `getElementBy...` methods. You can use any css selector.

Comment: Hi, for the second part, I've inserted this line of code: a.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"}); - following this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView - It works, but the element is not at the top, - it just creeps into view. For example, if you click on the link 'Test 17' in Level 13 at the bottom of the menu. Not sure why it's not quite working... : (

Comment: Check the `block` parameter again. If you want it at the top, it should be `start`. If you want it like microsoft, it should be `center`. But take care. It cannot scroll more than possible. If the scrolling comes to an end, it still might be not at the top as expected.

Comment: I did this: a.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest"}); it works very well. Thank you.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this one, for the right hand side ToC? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379328/how-do-modify-the-class-of-the-inline-toc-element-with-javascript

Comment: What do you want? Marking them with an active class to change styles? Basically you are doing the same, but you need to use window.location.hash and a.hash for comparison.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Marking the right one with an active class, specifically class="selected" - depending on the where the main page scroll position.

Comment: No, I'm still stuck.I think the JS algo needs to go something like. Identify id of h2 or h3 element in scrollable viewing area (should only return one result), then get the id of that element (with h2 or h3 tag), and match that id to the a.hash value in the RHS Toc. If there is a match, then add "selected" to class. But I'm stuck on how to do steps 1 and 2. Just reading this now: https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll

Comment: I'm using the IntersectionObserver at the bottom of  page here: https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll as a starting point

Comment: Try this and modify: 

`var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    let currentHeader = entries.find(x => x.isIntersecting)
 if (currentHeader)
  console.log(currentHeader.target, 'Element is fully visible in screen');
}, { threshold: [1] });

document.querySelectorAll("main h2").forEach(elem => observer.observe(elem));`

Comment: Thanks. I modified the function, a bit, as it kept firing back true, twice - I set the threshold to [0], and wrapped the call back in a foreach. See here: https://startech-enterprises.github.io/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html (but still not quite getting the right behaviour (e.g. if scrolling through a very long section, and the header disappears from the viewport)... I'll put the JS I'm using here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379328/how-do-modify-the-class-of-the-inline-toc-element-with-javascript

Comment: Hi Paul, any ideas on how to solve this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901267/navigating-back-to-search-page-with-same-state-javascript