# How do modify the class of the inline toc element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**QUESTION**

Hi, I am creating a simple navigation site, and would like to know how to change / add a class to one of the li elements of the inline toc, on the right, to style it with css

My page so far.

https://startech-enterprises.github.io/docs/data-integration-and-etl/branches-and-loops-local.html

The page behaviour I'd like to achieve:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops-local

(if you scroll up and down the main page, you will see the styling of the right side toc element change)

The same behaviour can be seen here:
https://startech-enterprises.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/quick-start-guide/
(see right hand side toc change as you scroll up and down the page)

I've tried to study the JavaScript behind this pages, but it's difficult to make sense of, and the scripts look overly complicated.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Sachin

**NOTE** - *QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED AND CODE in link above UPDATED, based on answers given below*

**CODE USED**

*The CSS I have so far:*

```
.doc-outline ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.doc-outline ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.doc-outline li.selected {
  font-weight: 600;
  border-color: #0065b3;
}

.doc-outline a:visited {
  color: #0065b3;
}
```

*Relevant portions of HTML*

```
   <div class="primary-holder column is-two-thirds-tablet is-three-quarters-desktop">
      <div class="columns has-large-gaps is-gapless-mobile">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE --!>
        <div id="main-column" class="column is-full is-four-fifths-desktop">
          <main id="main" class ="content" lang="eng-us">
            <h1 id="learn-conditional-logic-with-branch-and-loop-statements">Learn conditional logic with branch and loop statements</h1>.....etc.
          </main>   
        </div>

       <!-- RHS TOC GOES HERE --!>
       <div class="right-sidebar column is-one-quarter is-one-fifth-desktop is-hidden-mobile is-hidden-tablet-only">
        <nav class="doc-outline is-fixed is-vertically-scrollable", id="affixed-right-sidebar">
        <nav id="side-doc-outline">
         <ul class="section-nav">
           <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#make-decisions-using-the-if-statement">Make decisions using the if statement</a></li>
           <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#make-if-and-else-work-together">Make if and else work together</a></li>
           <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#use-loops-to-repeat-operations">Use loops to repeat operations</a></li>
           <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#work-with-the-for-loop">Work with the for loop</a></li>
           <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#created-nested-loops">Created nested loops</a>
           <ul>
            <li class="toc-entry toc-h3"><a href="#test">Test</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#combine-branches-and-loops">Combine branches and loops</a></li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
      </nav>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
```

*JavaScript*

*EDIT* (Final JS used in link above, incorpoating ideas / comments from answers below) - scope to possibly simplify some of the code blocks..

*Highlight correct RHS TOC Menu Item*

```
(function rhsToc() {
// initialise global variables outside functions
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, { threshold: [0] });
let selection;
let headings = [...document.querySelectorAll("#main h2, #main h3")];
let rhsToc = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.section-nav a")];
let a = null;
let lastScroll = 0;
let headingMenuMap = headings.reduce((acc, h) => {
    let id = h.id;
    acc[id] = rhsToc.find(a => a.getAttribute("href") === "#" + id);
    return acc;
  }, {})

headings.forEach(elem => observer.observe(elem));

// detect scroll direction
scrollDetect();
let scrollDirection = [];
function scrollDetect(){
    var lastScroll = 0;
    window.onscroll = function() {
        let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; // Get Current Scroll Value
        if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll){
          lastScroll = currentScroll;
          scrollDirection = "down";
        }else{
          lastScroll = currentScroll;
          scrollDirection = "up"
        }
    };
  }

function handler(entries) {

    // Update selection with current entries.
    selection = (selection || entries).map( s => entries.find(e => e.target.id === s.target.id) || s);

    // keep only true values
    filteredArr = selection.filter(x => x.isIntersecting == true );

    // Find last visible/intersecting (use a copied array for that, since reverse is an in place method)
    let firstVisibleId = [...selection].find(x => x.isIntersecting) ? [...selection].find(x => x.isIntersecting).target.id : null;

    // Is a firstVisibleId returned? If not, then follow the below steps
    if (firstVisibleId === null){
        // were you scrolling down? - then do nothing
        if (scrollDirection == "down"){
            // do nothing!
        } else {
            // scrolling up - so remove 'selected' from current menu item, and add it to the menu item above it
            const current = document.querySelector(`#side-doc-outline > ul li.selected`);
            if (current) {
                current.classList.remove('selected');
            }
            // if there is no previous sibling with a class of 'toc-entry', you're at top of branch, so go up a level, provided you don't get to section-nav
            if(previousByClass(a.parentElement, "toc-entry") == null){
                parent_by_selector(a.parentElement, "ul:not(.section-nav)") ? parent_by_selector(a.parentElement, "ul:not(.section-nav)").parentElement.classList.add("selected") : null;
            } else {
                previousByClass(a.parentElement, "toc-entry") ? previousByClass(a.parentElement, "toc-entry").classList.add("selected") : null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    // otherwise, remove 'selected' from the active item in the RHS toc
    const current = document.querySelector(`#side-doc-outline > ul li.selected`);
    if (current) {
        current.classList.remove('selected');
    }

    // add 'selected' to the target item in the RHS toc
    for (s of selection) {
        let targetId = s.target.id;
        // get the entry from the generated map.
        a = headingMenuMap[targetId];
        if (firstVisibleId === targetId) {
            a.parentElement.classList.add("selected");
            return;
        } 
    };
}

})();

// WAIT TILL DOCUMENT HAS LOADED BEFORE INITIATING FUNCTIONS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tree);
```

Comment: Try jQuery toggleClass or addClass

Comment: The problem is half solved. Except my page, doesn't quite give the same behaviour as: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops-local  (e.g. when two h2/h3s are in the viewport, or for long sections, where the h2/h3 tags disappear from the viewpoirt)

Comment: Problem fully solved based on comments, from Paul below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've surrounded the content for each section with a `paragraph` class, which is used for observing and also added a class to it's content `content` - which is actually used nowhere yet, but I would still suggest to do that.

EDIT: integrated your idea how to select the element in case of multiple intersections.

https://jsbin.com/cufeyoreno/edit?js,output

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, {
  threshold: [0.2]
});
let selection;
let paragraphs = [...document.querySelectorAll("#main .paragraph")];
let submenu = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.section-nav a")];
let paragraphMenuMap = paragraphs.reduce((acc, p) => {
  let id = p.firstElementChild.id;
  acc[id] = submenu.find(a => a.getAttribute("href") === "#" + id);
  return acc;
}, {})

paragraphs.forEach(elem => observer.observe(elem));

function handler(entries) {

  // Update selection with current entries.
  selection = (selection || entries).map(
    s => entries.find(e => e.target.firstElementChild.id === s.target.firstElementChild.id) || s
  );

  // Find last visible/intersecting (use a copied array for that, since reverse is an in place method)
  let lastVisibleId = [...selection].reverse().find(x => x.isIntersecting).target.firstElementChild.id;

  for (s of selection) {
    let targetId = s.target.firstElementChild.id;
    // avoid searching the dom and just get the entry from our map.
    let a = paragraphMenuMap[targetId];

    if (lastVisibleId === targetId) {
      let parentElem = a;
      // ensure that parent menu entries are selected too
      while (parentElem = parentElem.parentElement.closest(".toc-entry")) {
        parentElem.classList.add("selected");
      }
    } else {
      a.parentElement.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @Sachin I'm out for a while. I need a stackoverflow break. So, don't wonder for no more answers from my side. ;) Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've just seen your code. I think I've managed to solve the multiple entries are visible problem (with the updated JS code above) - I decided that if two elements are visible, to show the lowest element. The code is long, as the isIntersecting class is read only, so I had to create another array called visible - but I'm not sure if the code could be simplified in anyway. Thanks again for all your help. I will check again to see if I can solve the other part of the problem (long sections), with your code.

Comment: @Sachin Check this: https://jsbin.com/cufeyoreno/edit?js,output I integrated your idea and improved and simplified it. I edited my post too. Now I am out for real. ;)

Comment: Thanks again! It works well, but if you scroll  up, the last item remains highlighted... : ( I'm work on a full solution now, incorporating (rather reluctantly) a scroll event.. will post solution soon

Comment: Ok - finally done it. One of your lines for setting the selector, treplaced two big blocks of code, so that was v. helpful! Above is best I've been able to do so far. I wanted to put the scroll function for detecting the scroll direction, in the handler function, but it only updated when the handler function fired, and was I was getting glitchy behaviour (handler is an asynch function?), so I (relunctantly) put it in a window.onscroll wrapper - now... I do get the sticky menu behaviour I wanted - without needing wrapping 'p' tags. This was a lot, lot hard than I originally thought!

Comment: Hi Paul, any ideas on solving this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901267/navigating-back-to-search-page-with-same-state-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the answer you don't want to give it a style just add a class?
If you would like to directly give some stylings to a li e.g. you could do this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li").addEventListener("click",()=>{
 this.style = "color:red";
})
```

but I guess you want to add already prepared classes in that case you need ClasList

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
```

adds

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.remove("mystyle");
```

removes

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.toggle("mystyle");
```

toggles

in that case you need to add classes to them individually add ID's or same class to take each by class[0],class[1] etc... 
you need 2 things

```
 `document.body.scrollTop;`
```

and for each height add class as shown above 
e.g.

```
 if(document.body.scrollTop == 100px){
     document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
 }
```

and a better version if you want to remove from the previous

```
if(document.body.scrollTop == 100px){
    for(let i = 0;i<classOfLis.length,i++){
    classOfLis[i].classList.remove("selected");
}
    document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
}
```

Comment: Hi Nairi the class I want to add to the li, is just called "selected" - refer to the CSS script above which will apply the correct styling to any li, with the class "selected". So all the JavaScript needs to do is add "selected" to the class of the correct li tag, when that part of the page has been scrolled to, which is what I am trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: in that case you need to add classes to them individually add ID's or same class to take each by class[0],class[1] etc... 
you need 2 things 
    `document.body.scrollTop;`
and for each height add class as shown above 
e.g. if(document.body.scrollTop == 100px){
    document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
}

and a better version if you want to remove from the previous
if(document.body.scrollTop == 100px){
    for(let i = 0;i<classOfLis.length,i++){
    classOfLis[i].classList.remove("selected");
}
    document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
}

Comment: Thanks for your help Nairi. I have a working solution now above, based on the comments provided by Paul, and after some further thinking