# Navigating back to Search Page with same state (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I, using JavaScript, retain the state of the search page, when a user clicks into a search result, but then goes back to the main search page.

e.g.

**HTML**:
https://startech-enterprises.github.io/docs/guides/data-analytics/data-analytics.html

There are 5 elements that determine what is shown on the page:

- What tags are clicked in the three filter menus, on the side
- What search term is typed into the search menu bar, at the top
- The pagination page that is selected, at the bottom

Problem is that whenever I go into the search result, and navigate back to the main search page, the search page resets itself, so I have to re-enter the search criteria again - which can be quite annoying.

If I click 'back' in the browser, the search page state is retained, but the search script stops working. Also, using the 'browser' back button only goes back one 'link' - so if the user clicks on several links in any page (returned from the search), they have to press the 'back' button many times, to get back to the main search page - which again isn't ideal.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Would seem like a fairly common problem?

The site is purely static, (generated using Markdown and Jekyll). Site interactivity is set with Vanilla JavaScript, and SASS/SCSS.

Pls do help!

Many thanks in advance.

Sachin

***UPDATE:*** This has now been solved based on the answers given below

Comment: You could use something like [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the filters and then automatically enable them again ones the user goes back. For the other issue i suggest something like the [pageshow event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event). It fires whenever you restore a page

Comment: Thanks Reyno. Would this be done using JavaScript? Are you able to point me to any working examples, and I can explore further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by saving the data in users device . You can do it by using cookies or by localStorage. I prefer localStorage because users can deny cookies easily.
Like this-

```
localStorage.setItem("tags",tagItemsInAnArray);
```

And later`localStorage.getItem("tags");`

Comment: Thanks Hemant. Using LocalStorage, would I be able to store multiple variables - e.g. 3 separate arrays (for the 3 side filters on the page), and one string (for the search bar at the top), and a fifth one for pagination. If my objects are tagArray1, tagArray2, tagArray3, searchString, and an interger CurrentPage, how would I do it - as a simple example?

Comment: @Sachin You cannot store multiple variables in one item, unless you try to add as a stringified list. But there is a plus point- you can store many items in local storage and each with any name you want. So simply keep different items with different names. And please mark it the answer if your problem is sorted

Comment: I think for something like a filter `sessionStorage` is a better solution. Since `localStorage` will persist even if the browser closes.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try and study the storage functions and documentation, and get something up and running before the end of the day, and let you know how I progress

Comment: Thanks. It now works. The surfing experience is now much more fluid!

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage to keep the search filter data. The concept is to keep all filter data in an array and keep that array in the localStorage of the browser before any redirection. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is an official documentation with implementation of localStorage.

Here is a demo:

```
//before redirection
let filterData = [];
localStorage.setItem("searchFilter", JSON.stringify(filterData));

//after page-load
let cachedFilterData= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchFilter"));
if(cachedFilterData.length>0){
    //cache data exist
}

//when you need to delete cache
localStorage.removeItem("searchFilter");
```